# php htaccess folders management

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

For now i have all requests to my domain to go through /index.php

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on

RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

However i want to add an exception. If the request goes to folder "/this_specific_folder/" then it should go for "/this_specific_folder/index.php" instead of "/index.php", without breaking the current existing logic.

How can i achieve this?

Comment: `RewriteRule ^(/?this_specific_folder)/?$" $1/index.php [L]` this should work if it's a real path.

Comment: Didn't work. The "/this_specific_folder" is a real path, but if i add other folder (not real) to the path "/this_specific_folder/this_not_real_subfolder", it gets redirected to the root "/index.php"

Comment: Correct the question. Should it be /this_specific_folder/non-real-path -> /this_specific_folder/index.php, and /this_specific_folder/real-path -> /this_specific_folder/real-path ?

Comment: After /this_specific_folder there are no real subfolders. It should be possible to do /this_psecific_folder/path1/path2 and this should be redirected to /this_specific_folder/index.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can have it this way:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(this_specific_folder)(?:/.*)?$ /$1/index.php [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.+)/$ $1 [L,R=301]    

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: Same behaviour as previous comment. if i add other folder (not real) to the path "/this_specific_folder/this_not_real_subfolder", it gets redirected to the root "/index.php"

Comment: It gives a 500 Error response

Comment: i think it should be duplicate of the last rule with `!-f` checking, but with prefix `^this_specific_folder/` in rule.